# почему alert не выводит русского/украинского текста?

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно выполнить задание:

> Создайте функцию `hello()`, при вызове которой будет выводится строка 
>   «Привет, JavaScript!».

Вот мой код:

```js
function hello() {
  alert("Привет, JavaScript!");
}
hello();
```

И вот что получается в результате:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так,  чтобы текст воспринимался адекватно?

Comment: :-D а jQuery-то там зачем? :-) судя по всему проблема в кодировке (страницы или файла)

Comment: Как вариант попробуйте `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: @AlexanderIgorevich, возможно не сработает если сам файл в другой кодировке

Comment: спасибо, да, проблема была в кодировке.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему проблема в кодировке (страницы или файла).

Answer (score 2):

Смени на кодировку Юникод или же UTF-8 with BOM

Comment: достаточно просто <meta charset = "utf-8">

Comment: @АлександрПиткевич по хорошему надо всё приводить к одной кодировке.

Comment: @lampa <meta charset = "utf-8"> в <head> решает такие вопросы :)

Comment: @АлександрПиткевич он решает эти вопросы, когда парсер браузера дошел до него. Сохранять файл в utf-8, а также передавать в заголовках Content-Type с правильной кодировкой.

Comment: Даже поле вставки  <meta charset = "utf-8">  может не помочь